# Python: Is there a Runtime Variable explorer available?

Tags: python, debugging

I am looking for a software like a database explorer which shows me all variables, functions etc. of a running python app and allows me to browse their content.

Now I am saving or printing variables to a logfile to debug my software, - to see what its actually doing- for example
print b
print a
c=a+b
logfile('a+b is: '+c)

Thats annoying
Thx

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: Also, depending on the IDE you use, it has a debugger. PyCharm, for example, allows you to see your variables, add break points, and more

Comment: Ok, thx. Do you know of a very simple program for that task, PyCharm look huge..

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want to see everything, you need the [python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

I'm a backend programmer now for almost 10 years and I never needed to learn how to use a debugger. I did my debugging with punctual messages and specific var dumps where I wasn't certain what happens.

Comment: Thx, I am logging a lot, but that drives me crazy, as Kate or Gedit just take ages to 1) detect changes in the logs 2) load them.. If python debugger is the thing to do, I will look into that (I am a novice programmer and that stuff looks very complicated..).

Comment: yeah, that's what stopped me learning working with a debugger also. Don't you use tail in order to watch the logs?

Comment: thx, good idea. i now found out that komodo can automatically reload and it does not stall with big files.